# Is there a way using "isToday" with Bar Replay?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I use a time related switch to change styling of lines if 'isToday' is true.

Simplified:

```
if isToday
    DoThis
else
    DoThat
```

This works on the real chart, if "today" really equals today, but it doesnt do its job while using Bar replay (obviously, since, e.g. todays timestamp, remains today (timestamp).

I might be doing something wrong and seek a way to backtest my script using Bar Replay.

Any idea? Someone?

Note:
Using `[ ]` history-referencing operator is not an option since I am using this in a nested function that relies on comparing 'event date/time' (today/currentWeek/currentMonth).

I hoped there is a dev switch or something I miss, allowing to use BarReplay maybe in a different fashion?

Comment: Just to clarify your question, you want to use bar replay and while you do it you want to have the currently played day to be drawn with a different style?
If you try to implement some debug mode Tradingview forgot to include in Pine, you are better off with  `plotshape()`. You have infinite amount of that, so you can draw the same shape over every bar, but you can play with color (based on condition) so you can either not plot the shape or plot it but being 100% transparent.
Using an `isToday()` type of condition is useless as it will be always `true`.

Comment: Thanks mate. Will be looking into this option.